# Is it possible to do monorepo with one azure build for several nuget packages?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, nuget-package, continuous-deployment

It is little noisy when you have 10 repositories with 10 nuget packages.

I would like to have one repository with 10 nuget packages, but I need one Azure Build with publish only changed nuget packages step and ignore at all unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. I would recommend for you multiple pipelines one per package with limited [CI trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) to package folder (you can have many build in one repo, you only need a separate YAML files for them):

```yaml
# specific path build
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - package-1/*
    exclude:
    - `*`
```

You can use this with combination to [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) as most of steps probably will be the same from all your builds. They will have only different parameter values. You can also take a look on my [blog post](http://thecodemanual.pl/2020/04/02/build-templates-on-azure-devops.html) where I wrote about templates.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are properly versioning each nuget package independently, it shouldn't be a problem. The nuget feeds don't allow duplicate package names.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/publish-a-package